# How to install Firefox 3.5 along with 3

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

I'm using Windows and want to use Firefox 3.5 side-by-side with the older 3.0.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do this is install Firefox 3.0 on your computer, then download [Portable Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) to run version 3.5.

Answer (score 6):

Use **[Portable Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)**. It doesn't need to be installed onto a USB device; installing it onto your hard disk is perfectly fine.

Scroll down the page linked to above and look for the **Legacy Versions** section to download older versions.

[image: Where to download Firefox Portable]

I also use a Portable Firefox as a seperate 'dev' version which is loaded with all of my dev-centric add-ons. This keeps my normal day-to-day Firefox clutter-free and much lighter.

Answer (score 2):

(I haven't tried this approach with 3.5, but this worked with 2.0 and 3.0.)

Just install any desired versions of Firefox to their own directory. As long as you use a different profile for each version, there shouldn't be any issues with the various versions co-existing.

Once you have created the profiles for each version, you can specify the profile Firefox should use so that you don't have to chose one every time. See [MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) for the list of Firefox arguments.